# How to protect data validation from pasting in excel online?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel sheet which I'm sharing using excel online. The data validation rules keep breaking due to people copying and pasting into the page.

I am aware of this previous answer:
[How to protect data validation to fail while copy and paste data?](https://superuser.com/questions/617589/how-to-protect-data-validation-to-fail-while-copy-and-paste-data)

However, the solution makes use of VBA which of course isn't allowed on excel online.

Is there really no way of preventing this issue? Bar, of course, training users not to paste or only to paste values. Why does excel make this the default behaviour?

I'd be greatful for any assistance, even if it is telling me this can't be done.

Answer (score 1):

You might add [conditional formatting](https://excelribbon.tips.net/T007073_Conditional_Format_that_Checks_for_Data_Type.html) to cells to validate data type. For example, change the background to red if non-numeric data is entered into a numeric field, or yellow if outside a range. Though it wouldn't *prevent* users from mangling a shared sheet, at least it would help train them and make issues obvious.